# Finding the current value of a javascript variable produced by my browser

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to train a neural network to play a browser based game using evolutionary computing, and to do this I need to track the game score.

The game is created using only html, css and javascript, and the game score is being held in a specific variable in the js-script that my browser runs. When you play, the value of that variable does of course change and is local to my browser.

Is there any way to track the value of that variable in a Python script? (If I need to use other programming languages I'm willing to try that as well!)

EDIT: To be more specific:

The game in question: http://wayou.github.io/t-rex-runner/

The game uses this javascript: http://wayou.github.io/t-rex-runner/index.js

I need to track the value that is held by the variable `distanceRan` when the js-script above is being run by my browser. That variable is local to my computer, and should be able to be found in *my* memory, if I understand things correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I can think of two broad approaches you could try use; rapid scraping of the page or using a web framework like flask to host a webapp that can communicate via something like Ajax between the front and back end. I think this is too broad a starting point, we'd need more specifics

Comment: Is the score not visible on the page?

Comment: @epascarello It is.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to send data form a client (browser) to a server you usually want to send and HTTP request to your server with the data. For this you can for instance use the `XMLHttpRequest`. This allows you to send data to a server and receive a response. Here is an example:

```js
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/kuma/contributors";

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
oReq.open("get", url, true);
oReq.send();
```

[Example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I might misunderstand you here, I'm not very good at this, but what you suggest is to listen to the traffic between my browser and the website, right?

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any traffic besides just loading the website initially. You can play the game offline after loading it. I don't think my browser is sending the game score to the server in any way.

Comment: No that's what I'm assuming. My code example is a way to achieve this communication between client and server

Comment: Oh, right, I think I understand now. The idea is to set up a local server and then get the client to send the data to that server?

Comment: Exactly! There are multiple ways to achieve this but the one I showed you is a popular method used a lot nowadays ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the browser send some kind of [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for it to interact with outside scripts. You could set up a local python server on your machine.

Comment: Could you explain it to me like I'm 5? :)